# How to split from one textbox into multi-column datagridview via datatable in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm Trying to split from one textbox into multi-column datagridview via datatable in VB.NET.

So I did a 2D barcode scanner with a QR barcode label via event in textbox.

is there something wrong with my code?. Please Guide me

Thanks

```
Public Class Form2
    Public testtable As New DataTable()
    Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnLoad(e)
        testtable.Columns.AddRange({
        New DataColumn("No", GetType(Integer)),
        New DataColumn("Criteria1", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Criteria2", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Criteria3", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Criteria4", GetType(String)),
        New DataColumn("Criteria5", GetType(String))})
    End Sub
    Private Sub parseBarcodeScan(input As String)
        Dim split = input.Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Function(s) s.Trim())
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If e.KeyChar = Chr(13) Then
            parseBarcodeScan(TextBox1.Text)
            Try
                testtable.Rows.Add(testtable.Rows.Count + 1, Split(0), Split(1), Split(3), Split(6), Split(8))
                DataGridView1.DataSource = testtable
                TextBox1.Clear()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Example of sample data in textbox :

A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I

the result of the code above :

| NO | Criteria1 | Criteria2 | Criteria3 | Criteria4 | Criteria5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | System.String[] | System.String[] | System.String[] | System.String[] | System.String[] |

Desired Result

| NO | Criteria1 | Criteria2 | Criteria3 | Criteria4 | Criteria5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | D | G | I |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `split` variable in the `parseBarcodeScan()` method is **local to the method**. When the method finishes, the variable is no longer in scope or accessible outside the method, and immediately becomes eligible for garbage collection.

When you later add `Split(0)`, `Split(1)`, `Split(2)` ... etc to the grid row, it's calling a different `Split()` method, rather than referencing the array in `parseBarcodeScan()`. This method returns an array. The code then implicitly calls `ToString()` on the returned arrays to show the output. This is why you see `System.String[]`.

To fix it, you might be tempted to declare `split` as an array at the class level, like `testtable`. But a better option is using a `Function` instead of a `Sub` for `parseBarcodeScan()` to **return the result**. We then realize none of the code inside the `Try`/`Catch` is ever likely to throw an exception, make another minor adjustment to reduce indentation, and end up with this:

```
Private Function parseBarcodeScan(input As String) As List(Of String)
    Return input.Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Function(s) s.Trim()).ToList()
End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar <> Chr(13) Then Return

    Dim items = parseBarcodeScan(TextBox1.Text)
    testtable.Rows.Add(testtable.Rows.Count + 1, items(0), items(1), items(3), items(6), items(8))
    DataGridView1.DataSource = testtable
    TextBox1.Clear()
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this line code `Return input.Split({","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(Function(s) s.Trim()).ToList()` 
after this code it should be `End Function`

Comment: @siwa86 Yes, missed that when making the change. It's fixed now.

Comment: I have another post maybe you can help . [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78047884/how-to-make-a-column-datatable-expression-multiple-lines-in-vb-net?noredirect=1#comment137593918_78047884)